# Enable log in release version of app

Tags: android

I need to enable logging in my Android's release version. Nothing is currently showing up in LogCat. I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1. Is there something in Gradle that I need to include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you could try.

1) Restart Android Studio and/or your computer. If you're using adb twice or more (e.g. in the terminal as well), things get confused.

2) Make sure you don't have a Logcat filter applied.

3) If you see "Devices | Logcat" it means you have both pieces of content in the same place, and might have accidentally made the Logcat part take up no space – try looking for a resizeable border that you can move to make them sized better.

Comment: The message in the dropdown next to the device showed the word "Dead". Exiting Android Studio and restarting it solved the problem. Thanks!